# Clearing the TextBox values in Update Panel when dropdown index changed in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I want to clear the Text field's values which is taken in Update panel but because of update panel the values are not getting cleared. It is not finding the TextBox control declared inside the Update panel in .aspx. So, when DropDown selected index changes, I want to reset the text fields values. Can anybody please help me out?

Here is my C# code for clearing the textfield's values:

```
void ClearInputs(ControlCollection ctrls)
    {
       foreach (Control ctrl in ctrls)
       {

           if (ctrl is TextBox)

                ((TextBox)ctrl).Text = String.Empty;

                ClearInputs(ctrls.Controls);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the relevent code

Answer (score 0):

to find textbox in updatepanel use

`TextBox tb = (TextBox)updatepanel1.FindControl("textbboxid");`

use update panel mode `conditional` and do `updatepanel1.Update();` after cleaning your textboxes

Comment: @AniketPanke what exception r u getting.. Please share complete code in your question so I can help better..

Comment: "An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred in System.Web.dll." - I am getting this exception. on the following line:foreach (Control ctrl in ctrls)
       {
           TextBox tb = (TextBox)UpdatePanel2.FindControl("txtActualForceAthleteHorizontal");

Comment: @AniketPanke no need of foreach loop, u will get textbox without foreach loop.. Just use - TextBox tb = (TextBox)UpdatePanel2.FindControl("txtActualForceAthleteHorizontal");

Comment: But i want to clear the textbox values after finding the control, so can you please tell me how can I do that..I mentioned my coding above in the question

Comment: @AniketPanke Try this ONLY- TextBox tb = (TextBox)UpdatePanel2.FindControl("txtActualForceAthleteHorizontal"); it will find automatic in updatepanel2

Comment: Yes, I already used it but it just finding the control but not clearing the values  after dropdown index changes, so please tell me where and how to use the code?

Comment: @AniketPanke hahah u can't clear data after finding control? TextBox tb = (TextBox)UpdatePanel2.FindControl("txtActualForceAthleteHorizontal"); then use tb.Text = ""; or use ((TextBox)UpdatePanel2.FindControl("txtActualForceAthleteHorizontal")).Text = "";

Comment: @AniketPanke now it should be complete by your self.. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
public void CleartextBoxes(Control parent)
      {
        foreach (Control x in parent.Controls)
        {
            if ((x.GetType() == typeof(TextBox)))
            {

                ((TextBox)(x)).Text = "";
            }

            if (x.HasControls())
            {
                CleartextBoxes(x);
            }
        }
    }
```

on your drop down change event call this funcation as:

```
CleartextBoxes(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok Try this, you have update panel with 20 textbox in it. In the Update panel get all textboxes in one div like this :

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
               <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager2" runat="server" ScriptMode="Release"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="div_d2">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <div runat="server" id="div_d">
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt1">
    </asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txt2"></asp:TextBox>
                </div>
            </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClear" Text="dasdas" OnClick="btnClear_Click" />
    </form>
```

When the textboxes are in the div the clear code will work like this example I show you :

```
protected void btnClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        clearText(div_d);
    }
    private void clearText(Control PanelID)
    {
        foreach (Control c in PanelID.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                TextBox thetextBox = c as TextBox;
                thetextBox.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Getting an exception in 'ctrls.Controls' mentioned in foreach loop...please help me out

Comment: also 'ctrl' argument is invalid for 'setControlTextEmpty'...so I took 'ctrls'..is it right or wrong

Comment: well ok have you try it wit setControlTextEmpty(ctrls);

Comment: if that is not helping I can give you one more try for solution just tell me to edin this one :)

Comment: Thanks..but again its not working...My debugger is still not reading the update panel textbox controls..its directly jumped from 'if loop' to 'if loop' ..do you have any idea why is this happening...??

Comment: can you post the html code on the update panel with the textbox ?

Comment: <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>TextBox Control</td></tr></table> :This is my brief code for textbox control in Update panel.

Comment: in the Textbox Control there are around 20 textboxes fields which need to get cleared...please tell me what do I do?

Comment: ok that will do the stuff the problem is with the update panel you must get textboxes in div or something then you can get it with the loop and clear it